# Rails + Backbone - Backbone routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have push state enabled,

```
Backbone.history.start({
  pushState: true
});
```

When i try to click on this link,

```
 <a href="/page/all">All</a>
```

Its redirecting to the URL, but backbone routes is not working.

```
routes: {
    'aspect/:id':'aspect'
},
```

Am i missing anything?

**Update:**

I tried to add it in events but still its not working,

Template:

```
<a href="/page/all" class="user_aspects">All</a>
```

View:

```
events: {
    'click .user_aspects': 'aspects_list'
},
aspects_list: function(){
    alert(2)
}
```

Do i need to write it in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent clicking and execute `navigate` method manually.
For example:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  router.navigate(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href'), true);
})
```

Please have a look:
https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/04cd6354b0e0276442a1ddc9cdbc889924489745/app/main.js#L22

Comment: I have Edited by question. But just saw your Edited answer. I will try this link.